# save Pandas dataframe values in a dictionary given criteria

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, pandas

I have a `pandas df` that contains numbers of visitors and the paths they chose before completing the conversion goal. Each row represents the path and the numbers of visitors chose the path, for example, row1: 18 visitors visited '(entrance)' --> '/' --> '/ContactUS'/Default.aspx' before reaching the target goal

I'm only interested in the product page that a visitor was at last and I'm trying to create a dictionary that takes product name, such as 'VFB25AEH' as the key and # of visits as the value

```
Step1                        Step2                  Step3              Visits 
/ContactUs/Default.aspx        /                    (entrance)          18    
/Products/GBR100L.aspx  /Products/VFB25AEH.aspx   /Products/RAD80L.aspx  9    
/Products/VFB25AEH.aspx  (entrance)                 (not set)            5    
/Products/RAD80L.aspx    (entrance)                 (not set)            4
```

The following is my code that loops through each column of each row, and save the first product page (step that contains '/Products/') and save the total number of visits in a dictionary

```
result = {}
for i, row in enumerate(df.values):
    for c in row:
        if 'products' in str(c).lower():
            c = c.strip('.aspx').split('/')[2]
            if c in result:
                result[c]+= 1
            result[c] = 1
```

Ideal result is - result['VFB25AEH'] = 5, result['RAD80L'] = 4, result['GBR100L']=9

but, it turns out that the values in result were all '1'. Can someone help point out the error here??

Comment: I note that (separately to the problem detailed in my answer below) your code is not actually summing up the number of visits, but just counting the number of times a particular product ID appears in the data frame. Is that what you were intending?

Comment: Hello thanks for your quick reply! my intention was to sum up the number of visits of a particular ID. I'm only interested in the last product ID / product page appears in each row if there's any (step1 means the previous page before goal, step2 means 2nd previous page before goal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last 3 lines of your code reset `result[c]` back to 1 every iteration. Instead you need:

```
if c in result:
    result[c] += 1
else:
    result[c] = 1
```

You could alternatively use `collections.defaultdict`

```
import collections

result = collections.defaultdict(int)
for i, row in enumerate(df.values):
    for c in row:
        if 'products' in str(c).lower():
            c = c.strip('.aspx').split('/')[2]
            result[c] += 1
```

**EDIT**

Taking into account the requirement to sum up the number of visits, and take only the most recent product page visited:

```
import collections

result = collections.defaultdict(int)
for row in df.values:
    for c in row:
        if 'products' in str(c).lower():
            c = c.strip('.aspx').split('/')[2]

            # The number of visits is in the last entry in the row
            result[c] += row[-1]

            # We've found the most recent product page, so move on to the next row
            break
```

You don't actually need the call to `enumerate()` - you weren't using the index at all.

Comment: Thank you! The code works! But the numbers were a bit off. Not sure why.